# Google Apps Script: Line up timestamps following two different triggers using the onEdit() function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm creating a log for when students leave the classroom. Whenever I check the box beside their name, the log gets filled with the student's name, class and time out of class. When the box becomes unchecked, the time back in gets entered in the log.

As you can see from the image however, the time back in gets entered on a new line.

[Example of what's happening with the current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu7S7.png)

Is it possible through scripting to get the time back in class to line up with the previous line if it's the same student? Ideally this would work with more than one student out of class at the same time.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  // Variable to establish spreadsheet and range selected.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

    // Variable to call on the 'Activity Log' spreadsheet.
    var aL = ss.getSheetByName("Log");

    // Variable to swap to the next row in the Activity Log every time a box is checked.
    var spot = aL.getLastRow() + 1;

    // Variable for the timestamp.
    var CurrentDate = new Date();
  
// These variables are defined. Just shortening the code for conciseness.
    var Student = [sn,hr,ln];
    var Log = [StudentName,Homeroom,List];

    if (r.getValue() == true) {
      for (var i = 0; i < Student.length ; i++){
          Log[i].setValue(Student[i])
      };
      aL.getRange(spot,4).setValue(CurrentDate);
    }
    
    if (r.getValue() == false) {
      aL.getRange(spot, 5).setValue(CurrentDate);
    }
}
```

The last four lines are from the original code. I know that's why the info appears on the new row... I don't understand why the 'for' element won't check if the students names match the row however. If this is possible, I could delete the last four lines of code.

I hope I'm being clear enough in what I want.

Comment: wr is undefined

Comment: Oops sorry. 'wr' is part of the larger code but isn't necessary for what I'm trying to achieve. I removed it.

Comment: You did a pretty nice job on your code.  I enjoyed working with it. Although I tend to try to use the event object parameters a bit more.  I may actually be a bit compulsive about it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually in the process of revamping it to make it a little more efficient, and reduce the amount of redundant lines. I just need to figure out this last piece of the puzzle, and I should be "happy" with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used PropertiesService.getUserProperties() to store the row numbers.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() != "Log" && e.range.columnStart == 2) {
   sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setBackground('#ffff00');
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Log");
    var spot = tsh.getLastRow() + 1;
    var CurrentDate = new Date();
    var sn = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1);
    var hr = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 3);
    var br = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4);
    var Student = [sn, hr, br];
    var StudentName = tsh.getRange(spot, 1);
    var Homeroom = tsh.getRange(spot, 2);
    var List = tsh.getRange(spot, 3);
    var TimeOut = tsh.getRange(spot, 4);
    var TimeIn = tsh.getRange(spot, 5);
    var Log = [StudentName, Homeroom, List, TimeOut, TimeIn];
    if (e.value == 'TRUE') {
      e.source.toast('leave');
      Student[0].copyTo(Log[0]);
      Student[1].copyTo(Log[1]);
      Student[2].copyTo(Log[2]);
      Log[3].setValue(CurrentDate);
      let psObj = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperties();
      psObj[Student.map(r => r.getValue()).join()] = spot;//this saves the current row number in the user properties so that it will be available for their return.
      PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperties(psObj);
    }
    if (e.value == 'FALSE') {
      e.source.toast('return');
      let oldspot = parseInt(PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperties()[Student.map(r => r.getValue()).join()]);//This gets the last row used in the log sheet
      tsh.getRange(oldspot, 5).setValue(CurrentDate);
    }
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setBackground('#ffffff');
  }
}
```

This is what my active sheet looks like:

The second column is check box values

| Student |  | Class | List |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | FALSE | C1 | L1 |
| S2 | FALSE | C2 | L2 |
| S3 | FALSE | C3 | L3 |
| S4 | FALSE | C4 | L4 |
| S5 | FALSE | C5 | L5 |
| S6 | FALSE | C6 | L6 |

This is what my log looks like:

| Student | Class | List | Time Out | Time In |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | C1 | L1 | 4/30/2021 14:14:08 | 4/30/2021 14:14:14 |
| S1 | C1 | L1 | 4/30/2021 14:14:19 | 4/30/2021 14:14:25 |
| S1 | C1 | L1 | 4/30/2021 14:15:01 | 4/30/2021 14:17:09 |
| S2 | C2 | L2 | 4/30/2021 14:15:06 | 4/30/2021 14:17:43 |
| S3 | C3 | L3 | 4/30/2021 14:15:09 | 4/30/2021 14:17:02 |
| S4 | C4 | L4 | 4/30/2021 14:15:12 | 4/30/2021 14:17:53 |
| S5 | C5 | L5 | 4/30/2021 14:15:14 | 4/30/2021 14:17:55 |
| S6 | C6 | L6 | 4/30/2021 14:15:17 | 4/30/2021 14:16:48 |

and this is the content of the UserProperties object:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| S5,C5,L5 | 8 |
| S4,C4,L4 | 7 |
| S1,C1,L1 | 4 |
| S3,C3,L3 | 6 |
| S2,C2,L2 | 5 |
| S6,C6,L6 | 9 |

These are couple of extra functions for managing the UserPropertiesObject:

```
function getUserProps() {
  let uObj=PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperties();
  let keys = Object.keys(uObj);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  sh.clearContents();
  let a=[['Key','Value']];
  keys.forEach(k => {a.push([k,uObj[k]]);});
  sh.getRange(1,1,a.length, a[0].length).setValues(a);
}

function clearUserProps() {
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().deleteAllProperties();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  sh.clearContents();
}
```

Checking the checkboxes too fast will result in failures so I added the feature of highlight the box in yellow at the beginning of the script and then removing it at the end.  Any attempt to click before or during the yellow background will result in an error.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: I'll keep my working copy available for a few days in case you have some follow up questions.

Comment: Thanks @MetaMan! I've managed to implement some of these aspects into my own code. I tried to simple 'copy-paste' your code as a whole, and for some reason it doesn't output the same way as it does for you. My Log still puts the time back in class on a separate line, or it doesn't output anything at all.

Comment: Do you have access to PropertiesService?

Comment: And I just noticed the edit. It's the `oldspot` now. And look at that! It works!

One more question @MetaMan...Would this work if multiple people are editing at once? Let's say I wanted to have all the classrooms and allow everyone to edit? Would it still play nice?

Comment: Yes, they would all be editing this spreadsheet. I understand there could be some overlap if two people click on a student at once (and the script could theoretically not log them). My question is moreso whether the script would save the students' spots in PropertiesServices with multiple users.

Comment: If you have a lot of users editing the same spreadsheet, I think that would be a problem.  Some developers might suggest Lock Service but personally I've played around with it and in this case it doesn't solve the problems because you must check the box to generate an edit in order to get a trigger but if don't get the lock to open for you then you have a problem because your checkbox is already checked and unchecking in will cause another trigger.  So I would avoid it with lot's of users.

Comment: The script went well for approximately 30 staff members without the Lock Service. I will look into LockService for good measure to see if it is worth implementing or not. Thanks @MetaMan!